# Outlook 2010 added categories to all historical calendar and inbox items

Tags: outlook, ms-office

Using Outlook 2010 in an Exchange environment.

A category (green, if it matters?) has been assigned to every single calendar and inbox item, including those in subfolders. The user has said this happened when the category was renamed.

I'm not sure that it possible they have renamed and re-coloured the default category because new items just appear with no colour / category assigned to them.

I cannot find any information on how this might have happened - it seems that nobody else has ever done this - and have had no success by running the commandline switches to reset categories etc. Manually resetting categories  seems to work but this is a laborious task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can only happen if something other that Outlook iterated through all folders and items and reset the category. Any third party addins?

Look at the modified date of the items to narrow down when the change happened.

Comment: There are a few add-ins but none that involve categorising (as far as I know). I will investigate further tomorrow.